# How to print current variables gradients values with vars names in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to print current variables gradients values together with names for all variables.

I am using the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x_data = np.random.rand(100).astype(np.float32)
y_data = x_data * 0.1 + 0.3

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], -1.0, 1.0), name = "Wvar")
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]), name = "Bvar")
y = W * x_data + b

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - y_data))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5)
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss)

train = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for step in range(201):
     sess.run(train)
     if step % 50 == 0:
       for gv in grads_and_vars:
            print(str(sess.run(gv[0])) + " - " + str(sess.run(gv[1].name)))
            #print(step, sess.run(W), sess.run(b))
```

compute_gradients

> Returns: A list of (gradient, variable) pairs.

But I got not "GradValue" + VariableName format as expected, but just see values like `[-0.58050966]; [-0.33137798]` without variable names. How to print variables names also?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you noted, `compute_gradients` returns list of pairs (gradient, value). To print the value of the gradient, you need to `run` it inside a session. The names of variables, on the other hand, are static, so you just need to do:

```
for step in range(201):
     sess.run(train)
     if step % 50 == 0:
       for gv in grads_and_vars:
            print(str(sess.run(gv[0])) + " - " + gv[1].name)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but without more details it's rather hard to debug. Btw, this function changed the name in tensorflow since I wrote the answer to [gradients](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients).